# How can I create a destroy function to delete from database and if its saved change color of button

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, database, twitter-bootstrap

How can I create a destroy function to delete from the database, and if it is saved in the database, the color of the button changes to red, otherwise green. My form stores data correctly, but I can not destroy it.

**Blade**

```
@foreach (range(1, 3) as $item)
    <form method="post" action="/seats">
        @csrf
        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{Auth::user()->id}}"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="row_seats" value="4"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="seat_id" value="{{ $item }}"/>
        <button type="submit" style="width:60px; margin-left:10px;" 
            class="btn btn-success">
            {{$item}}
        </button>
    </form>

    <form method="POST" action="/seats/{{ $seats->id }}">
        <button type="submit" style="margin-left:10px;" class="btn btn-danger">
            Unreserve {{$item}}
        </button>
    </form>
@endforeach
```

**Destroy function**

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $seats = Seats::find($id);
    $seats->delete();
    
    return redirect('/seats');
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('/seats/{seats}',[App\Http\Controllers\SeatsController::class, 'destroy'])
    ->name('seats.destroy');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing the wrong variable to the destroy route which is the seat id in the foreach loop. change this

`action="/seats/{{ $seats->id }}"`
to

`action="{{ route('seats.destroy', $item) }}"`

Comment: Yes thank you it works . Now i am trying if its already stored in database showing only red button for delete.

Comment: you can check it with a if condition like this: `@if(App\Models\Seats::find($item))`

Comment: Do you know how can I prevent new line when I am using form in loop ? I tried  style="display: inline-block;" and div in different variants but it doesn't work , thank you !

Answer (score 0):

My destroy function already work.Now i am trying if it's already saved in database it is showing only red button for delete.

```
 @foreach (range(1, 3) as $item)

@if($seat_id > 0 )
<form method="post" action="{{ route('seats.destroy', $item) }}">
   @csrf
   @method('delete')

   <button type="submit"  style="margin-left:10px;"  class="btn btn-danger">Unreserve {{$item}}</button>

    </form>


    @else
<form method="post" action="/seats">
@csrf 
   
    <input type="hidden" name="row_seats" value="4"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="seat_id" value="{{ $item }}"/>
    <button type="submit"  style="width:60px; margin-left:10px;"  class="btn btn-success">{{$item}}</button>
    

    </form> 
    @endif

@endforeach
```

**Index function**

```
 $seat_id = $seats->id;
```

**if somebody need to see destroy function how it is created**

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
    $seats = Seats::find($id);

    if ($seats != null) {
        $seats->delete();
        return redirect('/seats')->with('success', 'Post Removed Succesfully !');
    }

    return redirect('/seats')->with('status','Something went wrong !');
       
    }
```